# ejb 3.1 timer to schedule 1st of every month

Tags: ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I want to schedule an EJB timer task to generate the reports in the early morning 2:00 AM, 1st of every month, round the year. I'd like to do this using the `@Schedule`. I used `@Schedule(dayOfMonth="1")`, is it right? It didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you try with this annotation `@Schedule(dayOfMonth="1", hour="2")`

Answer (score 0):

EJB 3.1 Final Release spec says:

> **18.2.1.2 Expression Rules**
>
> The second, minute, and hour attributes have a default value of “0”.
>
> The dayOfMonth, month, dayOfWeek, and year attributes have a default value of “*”.

So your

```
@Schedule(dayOfMonth="1")
```

means

```
@Schedule(dayOfMonth="1", second="0", minute="0", hour="0")
```

So it should be:

```
@Schedule(dayOfMonth="1", hour="2")
```

and that should do the trick.